# Download HTML Page (Which contains images with Base64 String) AS PDF With Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, json, pdf, base64

I have web page. This page contains lots of images which have base 64 string source. Normally I can download html web page as pdf with servise method. I send html page with json object. And Service method return pdf. But when I have  lots of images on web page (with base 64 string source) and than I can't send html page with json because of size (with long base 64 string). Now I must download page as pdf with js on client side with using jspdf or other libraries, Or other ways. How can I download html page (which contains images with long base 64 string source) as pdf on client side ? Which way should I follow..

for example this example download web page as pdf:
[JsFiddle Example Which Download HTML Page As PDF`code`](https://jsfiddle.net/damithz/Lo7kznLu/)

Bu when I add base 64 string source images to  this jsfiddle code  (to html) and than downloaded pdf can't show base64 string images..

Answer (score 0):

I would use server side :) I would use `phantomjs` on server side and return the screen capture to the client.

```
var page = require('webpage').create();
    page.open('http://github.com/', function() {
    page.render('github.png');
   phantom.exit();
});
```

[Read about screen capture](http://phantomjs.org/screen-capture.html)